# Add line break to ArcMap 10.2 label expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, javascript, arcgis-10.2, labeling

How can I add a line break to a jscript label expression? My expression so far looks like this

```
function FindLabel ( [NAME] )
{
  return [NAME]+'National Forest';
}
```

I would like to add a break after [NAME]

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out

```
function FindLabel ( [NAME] )
{
  return [NAME]+'\nNational Forest';
}
```